Golang request canceled error when performing a lot of concurrent requests
I created a simple program to test rps(maybe it's wrong, but question is not about that).
When i run it i see a lot of errors:
failed to perform request Get "https://somedomain.com": net/http: request canceled

and amount of such errors seems to depend on the server i send requests to. Errors are also printed right away after i launch the program, so it's not timeout issue i believe.
Why does this happen? The error has no other information than simply stating that request was cancelled.

go version go1.22.2 linux/amd64

Code i used for the test:
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
    "sync/atomic"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
            DialContext: (&net.Dialer{
                Timeout:   3 * time.Second,
                KeepAlive: 10 * time.Second,
                DualStack: true,
            }).DialContext,
        },
    }

    req, _ := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, "https://somedomain.com", nil)

    reqCntr := uint32(0)

    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    
    now := time.Now()

    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func ()  {
            defer wg.Done()
            resp, err := client.Do(req)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("falied to perform request %v\n", err)
                return
            }
            if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
                fmt.Printf("BAD STATUS CODE: %v\n", resp.StatusCode)
                return
            }
            atomic.AddUint32(&reqCntr, 1)
            resp.Body.Close()
        }()
    }

    wg.Wait()

    since := time.Since(now)

    fmt.Printf("Performed %v requests %v per second\n", reqCntr, reqCntr / uint32(since.Seconds()))
}


You may be getting blocked by a rate limiter

You have a 3 second timeout. Extend that and see what happens

@MattEvans errors are popping out right away. 3 seconds not have passed yet at the moment i start to see them

@BurakSerdar but what that error means? Server closed tcp connection?

A quick test shows that this doesn't happen if you actually create new requests instead of re-using the same pointer. So it looks like something triggers the "cancel request" signal, probably in some kind of cleanup. The net/http code is much to complicated for me to figure out exactly what though.

Request canceled means server closed connection without a response.

From the docs: "Callers should not mutate or reuse the request until the Response's Body has been closed" -- do not use the same request concurrently

@JimB i believe in my case it's fine since request has no body

@toozyfuzzy: that says the response's Body, not the Request. The transport is tracking all the concurrent requests as belonging to the same connection.

@JimB Oh, yes. Sorry, my bad. It seems that's the issue since as Jory Geerts mentioned if i don't reuse request object that doesn't happen

I think it can be helpful to print the resp.StatusCode when getting err from client.Do(req)`, like
fmt.Printf("falied to perform request %v\n with error code %v", err, resp.StatusCode)

@nimdrak the resp pointer is nil if Do returned non nil error

You're right. Sorry for misunderstanding
